# opendkim to sign all '*' users in a domain

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, opendkim

How do you get opendkim to sign for all users in a domain?

```
*@exmailer.com exmailmap
```

in the signing table is not working for me.

error:

```
opendkim[1565]: 573D4A0D3D: no signing table match for 'user@exmailer.com'
```

but,

```
user@exmailer.com exmailmap
```

works, but is not a very good solution since I have hundreds of users.

How do you get opendkim to sign for all users?

Comment: I use a wildcard exactly like that, so it should work. Note that in the error message it prints `exmail.com` while in the configuration you write `exmailer.com` -- just a typo?

Comment: @faker  yes, just a typo. I edited the question. I don't know why the wildcard is not working for me. I have checked for errors in logs and restarted opendkim, I can't find 'dumb' errors that would cause it.

Comment: And you are using `refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable` to include it? Or `file:/etc/...`?

Comment: Could you please post your full opendkim.conf? And the path of your signing table. Are there any other entries in the signing table? How does the Keytable look like?

Comment: @faker I was using refile instead of file.  Post it as an answer, i'll click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the signing table via:

```
 refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
```

Refile means that regular expressions get evaluated.
When it is included via `file:/...` regular expressions are not evaluated.